# The fundamental group of a half disk ( a neighborhood of a boundary point) can't be detected

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

In the lecture A professor said something I don't quite understand. We need to show that no interior point of a surfacce is a boundary point. We were showing that by proving the neighborhood $U$ of a interior point $x$ is **not** homotopy equivalent to the neighborhood $V$ of a boundary point **y**. Now here is the thing I don't understand: $\pi1(U)$ is certainly trivial and with $x$ removed is $\mathbb{Z}$. But the professor said the foundamental group of $V$ could not be detected and with $y$ removed is still a half disk. Could someone help me here? Perhaps I heard it wrong?

Comment: With $x$ removed you can find a 'loop' around it in your $\pi_1(U)$. Can you find an uncontractable loop in $\pi_1(V-y)$?